# How to create a custom Android view? Using XML objects or a drawing API?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a new view that would:

- load an image
- allow the user to zoom and rotate the image with two fingers while a "cropping box" stays translucent over the top while the image extends beyond the "cropping box"
- with the end goal of being able to mark the rotation and position of the main image (so that later i could crop out or show the area within the cropping box)

I'm wondering if I can do this with an `ImageView` holding the image in the background and another `ImageView` holding the crop box on top of it, then using `TouchEvents` to move the image, would this work?

Or do I need to use some drawing API on a 2D surface?

I'm just really new to creating custom objects in Android that aren't just customized out-of-the-box Views.

What's the standard way of creating something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Compound View` by extending `RelativeLayout` with two overlapping `ImageView`s in it. Then override `onTouch` event or override `onGestureDetector` interface in that newly created View.

Official Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html
Another Tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html